# Get-ADObject : Error parsing query Not supported: -neq'?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adobject?view=win10-ps

How can I get the result so that it only shows all active AD Users & Computers only:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter 'Enabled -eq $True -and isDeleted -neq $True -and -not (isRecycled -eq $True) -and name -ne "Deleted Objects"'
```

Error:

```
Get-ADObject : Error parsing query: 'Enabled -eq $True -and isDeleted -neq $True -and -not (isRecycled -eq $True) -and name -ne "Deleted Objects"' Error Message: 'Operator Not supported: -neq' at position:
'34'. At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADObject -Filter 'Enabled -eq $True -and isDeleted -neq $True -an ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADObject], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADObject
```

Comment: `-ne` instead of `-neq`?

Comment: Also, switch the quotes for the filter (single to double and vice versa

Comment: yes, that's correct and works. Thank you Von & Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really just looking for users & computers, use a query that says that:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "user" -or ObjectClass -eq "computer"'
```

Withstanding the already mentioned operator error, `Get-ADObject` can't double quote and use $true/$false inside.  Those will expand and come out as simply true/false.  Running a command like `Get-ADObject -Filter "Enabled -eq $true"` returns an error:

```
Get-ADObject : Error parsing query: 'Enabled -eq True' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '13'.
```

If you do run it with single quotes it'll run but in my environment it doesn't return anything, likely because "Enabled" isn't a query-able property from the more generic objects returned by `Get-ADObject` and unlike `Get-ADUser/Computer`.  So you'll have to play with the quoting and the query itself.

An aside why use something like `-not (isRecycled -eq $true)` when you can just say `isRecycled -eq $false`.  You've already got a relatively complex query on your hands, I'd chop the unnecessary inversions...

Comment: What's the difference with: Where-Object {@('user', 'computer') -contains $_.objectClass} ?

Comment: You can do that, but generally you'll want to move filters left for performance reasons.  In this case you want Active Directory (LDAP) doing the filtering as much as possible, otherwise you'll get every object in the domain and still have to execute the Where{}...  It's almost always true that a cmdlet's native filtering is going to be faster than post filtering with Where{} or ForEach etc...

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `-neq`. What you're looking for is `-ne`
Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1