# Filtering Get-ADObject to exclude specific Strings?

Tags: powershell

How can I exclude specific string collections

> CN=HealthMailbox478eb865ff384698bf3ff10c9c889f1c,CN=MonitoringMailboxes,CN=Microsoft
> Exchange System Objects,...
> CN=HealthMailbox7s7df7s7vn3421nifdfu,CN=MonitoringMailboxes,CN=Microsoft Exchange System Objects,...
>
> OU=Disabled Computers
> OU=Service Accounts

from the result of the script below:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "user" -or ObjectClass -eq "computer" -and isDeleted -ne $True -and isRecycled -eq $false -and name -ne "Deleted Objects"'
```

Updated as per @Theo:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter "ObjectClass -eq 'user' -or ObjectClass -eq 'computer' -and isDeleted -ne $True -and isRecycled -eq $false -and name -ne 'Deleted Objects'"
```

However, the error is still:

```
Get-ADObject : Error parsing query: 'ObjectClass -eq 'user' -or ObjectClass -eq 'computer' -and isDeleted -ne True -and isRecycled -eq False -and name -ne 'Deleted Objects'' 
Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '74'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADObject -Filter "ObjectClass -eq 'user' -or ObjectClass -eq 'com ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADObject], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADObject
```

Comment: The quoting is wrong. You should switch all single-quotes to double an all double-quotes to single. As it is, you are filtering on the literal string `$True`.

Comment: Usually AD -filter options don't work on distinguished names, and you have to pipe to where-object instead.

Comment: @js2010 agreed but he may be able to use wildcard patterns... Another refinement might be to exclude the OUs he definitely doesn't want.  Create an array of OU DNs, then pipe to `ForEach` runing 1 query per with `-SearchBase` specified.  Again an effort to have as little as possible being done in a post `Where{}`

Comment: @Theo, I've updated the quote as suggested, but it is still failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within the `-Filter` argument You'll have a hard time excluding on the basis of when a collection contains a value.  This may be a case to filter as much as you can on the left, but append a post filtering `Where{}` .  The rule is to filter "as much as you can, as far left as you can" (quotes are mine). There are always going to be cases where there's a little more to be done.  Something like:

```
$Exclusions = "Server1","Server2"
Get-ADObject ... | Where-Object{ $_.Name -notin $Exclusions }
```

Or:

```
Where-Object{ $Exclusions -notcontains $_.Name }
```

In similar cases I like to create a `$Exclusions` array, so it can be appended as needed while you are dev-ing or for later maintenance.

> Note: You may not need `-and isDeleted -ne $True` If the
> `-IncludeDeletedObjects' parameter is any indication` Get-ADObject`excludes them by default.  Also, as written it's another inversion, the literal idea "not deleted" is easier to read as`isDeleted -eq
> $false`

That said, and with the limited example above, you might be able to add `Name -notlike "HealthMailbox*"` to your filter string.  You could probably add additional `-and -notlike ...`, but who knows when that'll get out of hand.

As I mentioned in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63488518/4749264) Get-ADObject seems to reject double quoted queries as suggested in previous comments.  Granted this seems to be unusual and backwards behavior, but in testing Get-ADObject seems to expect expansion of $true/$false.  Replacing with single quotes just makes it fail.  Indeed and so far as I can tell the query as given in the question is working.  I invite others to comment...

Nevertheless [About_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7), doc may be a helpful refresher...

Note: The AD cmdlets are known to be finicky regarding the typing of the `-Filter`'s argument, so to a certain extend I'm not surprised.

Comment: the code is still failed to exclude the object.
$Exclusions = @(
   'SystemMailbox',
   'HealthMailbox',
   'Delete'
)
How can I use the above partial name list like the above?

Comment: Does the Get-ADObject can also filter (Enabled -eq $True)?
because it doesn't return anything when I add that additional filter.

Comment: You can use `-notmatch` or `-notlike` Example: `Where{ $_.Name -notlike "HealthMailbox*" -and $_.Name -notlike ... }` . However, as I mentioned with `-Filter` that could get long. With `-notmatch` try something like `Where{ $_.Name -notmatch "(^HealthMailbox|^SystemMailbox|^Delete)"}`. The pipe acts like an OR, the "^" means start with.  An aside: you may be conflating some of the help examples.  It's unlikely to have a user/computer named "delete*".  In their example the OU was being filtered out, but you are already filtering on objectClass... You need your own query.

Comment: I'm glad it's working out.  When you have a chance please mark as answered.